# How to count and output variables named in a specific numeric pattern

Tags: php

I have created few different strings with similar names, and I would like to display them all.

However, I will need to do this dynamically, because I will adding more of them, later on.

These strings are called:

- $group1
- $group2
- $group3
- $group4

My idea is to somehow count them all, and then display them with `for` loop. I just need help with counting part.

Comment: why don't you store these in an array?

Comment: because this script is not for me, i'm helping somebody. He said that would be easier for him to do this that way. :)

Comment: that doesn't mean its right. arrays are the right datastructure.

Comment: Try this function: `function countEm() { return 4; /* update as needed*/ }`

Comment: I know, and I would be able to do this with an array. However, as I said. I'm just helping, and anyway this knowledge would improve my skills, so I'm asking is somebody know how to do that

Comment: use `get_defined_vars()` to get all defined vars and `array_walk()` to filter them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Though arrays are definitely the superior and appropriate solution in this case*, since you insist in the comments that separate variables are required, you can solve this using a `while` loop to check for the existence of such consecutively named variables, creating the variable names dynamically with `{}`.

For example:

```
$group1 = '123';
$group2 = '456';
$group3 = '789';

$i=1;
while ($string = ${'group'.$i}) {
   echo $string;
   $i++;
}
```

Note how `${'group'.$i}` dynamically creates each variable name. Also, naturally this approach would fail if the variables are *not* named consecutively (e.g. if you have `$group1` followed by `$group3`). As said, you should definitely use an array for this.

### [See a live demo](http://ideone.com/TCPKqP)

Comment: that's genius in its simplicity. Thank you so much!

Comment: quite clean, I was using a for loop, but this is just squeaky clean, I see you have your gloves on :-)

Answer (score 2):

Associative arrays are designed exactly for this:

```
$arr = array(
    "group1" => "string1",
    "group2" => "string2",
    "group3" => "string3",
    "group4" => "string4",
);
```

Now to get the length of your array:

```
$num = count($arr);
```

To access the first element

```
$firstElement = $arr["group1"];
```

Alternatively you can use an indexed array (access elements by their position):

```
$arr = array("string1", "string2", "string3", "string4");
$firstElement = $arr[0];
$num = count($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to count+loop

```
$arr=array();
$add_to=array_push($arr,$group1);
$add_to=array_push($arr,$group2);
$add_to=array_push($arr,$group3);
$add_to=array_push($arr,$group4);

//count
echo count($arr);

//loop
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
echo $value;
}
```